# Исключение: Failed to set data for

Tags: c++builder, c++, исключения

Пишу прогу по добавлению параметров  в реестр, но всё бы не чего, всё получается, тут запустил антивирус и доступ к реестру через программу оказался закрыт и у меня исключение -

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class ERegistry with message 'Failed to set data for 'HungAppTimeout'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue .

Как обработать исключение с выводом сообщения о невозможности добавления параметра  помогите, пол интернета облазил не понял.

Вот исходник :

```
**{
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry;
reg->RootKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
reg->OpenKey("\Control Panel\\Desktop",true);  // Навернека строковый параметр
reg->WriteString("AutoEndTasks", 2);  // Auto closed programm
reg->CloseKey();

Application->MessageBox("Параметр добавлен, значение 2  ", "Registry", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
delete reg;

exit;
}**
```

Comment: наверное, ответ остался в другой половине, которую вы не облазили

Comment: Читал как обработать исключение при копировании файла, то что про файлы не подходит к реестру ....

Comment: @Programmist Syvorov, Вы снова делаете ту же ошибку, которую я пытался Вам растолковать в предыдущий раз. А заключается она в слешах.

И научитесь наконец вставлять правильно русский текст.

Comment: Ладно , причём тут слэши? Прога работает я смотрел на реестр и проверял. Проблема в исключении при работе антивируса ...

Comment: @KoVadim: интересно, _как_ можно вставить русский текст, чтобы он испортился? Разве что браузер виноват.

Comment: Можно, если у него система 64  битная, браузер также, а билдер старый, 32битный. Правда есть один старый трюк - перед копированием текста нужно переключиться на русский, и когда в броузере делать вставку - также на русский.

@Programmist Syvorov, да, слеши! в строке `"\Control Panel\\Desktop"` \C значит совсем другое. Должно быть либо `"Control Panel\\Desktop"`, либо `"\\Control Panel\\Desktop"`. Но мой комментарий будет снова проигнорирован.

Comment: @Programmist Syvorov: и правда, исправьте слеши, шансы на то, что это решит по крайней мере кусок проблемы, очень высоки.

Comment: Не решит нужно обработать исключение try { /* reg->WriteString("AutoEndTasks", 2); */ }
А здезь что  

catch (спецификация_параметра_исключения) { /* блок обработки */}, какой блок какая спецификация я обсалютно не понял расжуйте мне я уже неделю гадаю ....

Comment: Вот поможете мне с исключением я прогу выложу на обозрение в интернет, самые полезные параметры РУнЕтА!!! Честно я никогда не обрабатывал исключения работал на delphi и с этим не встречался помогите !!!

Comment: Просто Delphi не дал бы вам скомпилировать WriteString('ляляля',2). Типы какие попало, слэши как попало. Вам уже говорили, метод тыка тут не пойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

примерно так:

```
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry;
try
{
  try
  {
    reg->RootKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    reg->OpenKey("\Control Panel\\Desktop",true);  // Íàâåðíåêà ñòðîêîâûé ïàðàìåòð
    reg->WriteString("AutoEndTasks", 2);  // Auto closed programm
    reg->CloseKey();

    Application->MessageBox("Ïàðàìåòð äîáàâëåí, çíà÷åíèå 2  ", "Registry", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    Application->MessageBox("Шеф, всё пропало!!!", "Кабздец", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
  }
}
__finally
{
  delete reg;
}
```